# Is it possible to make a relative binding with the same command?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF and MVVM and I have the following question

1. I have 3 buttons
2. When I click on one button, it gets an `CommandParameter`, for example: 0,1
3. The Command `SetBackGround` splits the `CommandParameter` for extract row and column
4. Now I try the binding with `IsSelected` that has conditions and `Background` for setting the `Background`
5. The problem is... when I click all the buttons, they set a yellow `Background`, but I only need the buttons that **have the right condition**, so..

Do I need to make a different background for each button, or does an other way exist?

Who say.. if this conditions "parameters" set that background to yellow, and the others - not.

**Image**

[image]

**ViewModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Testing00.Commands;

namespace Testing00.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public ICommand SetBackGroundCommand { get; set; }
        bool LeftSelected { get; set; }
        bool RightSelected { get; set; }

        #region Methods
        int row;
        public int Row
        {
            get { return row; }
            set { row = value; }
        }

        int column;
        public int Column
        {
            get { return column; }
            set { column = value; }
        }

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get
            {
                if (row == 0 && column == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {

                    return true;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
                OnPropertyChanged("Background");
            }
        }

        public string Background
        {
            get
            {
                return IsSelected ? "Yellow" : "Transparent";
            }
        }

        #endregion


        #region Constructor

        public ViewModel()
        {
            SetBackGroundCommand = new RelayCommand(SetBackGround, param => true);
        }

        #endregion

        private void SetBackGround(object obj)
        {
            string[] commandParametters = obj.ToString().Split(',');
            Row = Convert.ToInt32(commandParametters[0]);
            Column = Convert.ToInt32(commandParametters[1]);
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            OnPropertyChanged("BackGround");
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**MainWindows**

```
<Window x:Class="Testing00.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:TEST="clr-namespace:Testing00.ViewModels"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Testing00"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <TEST:ViewModel x:Key="testVM"></TEST:ViewModel>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,109,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" Height="81"    CommandParameter="0,0" Command="{Binding SetBackGroundCommand, Source={StaticResource testVM}}" Background="{Binding Background, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource testVM}}"    />
        <Button Content="0,1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="208,109,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" Height="81" CommandParameter="0,1" Command="{Binding SetBackGroundCommand, Source={StaticResource testVM}}"  Background="{Binding Background, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource testVM}}" />
        <Button Content="0,2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="341,109,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" Height="81"  CommandParameter="0,2" Command="{Binding SetBackGroundCommand, Source={StaticResource testVM}}"  Background="{Binding Background, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource testVM}}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**RelayCommand**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Testing00.Commands
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {

        Action<object> _execute;
        Func<object, bool> _canexecute;
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canexecute)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canexecute = canexecute;

        }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (_canexecute != null)
            {
                return _canexecute(parameter);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This reads like an XY problem... maybe you can explain a bit more about what you want to do with the buttons and why the viewmodel should care about the selected button (and what a selected button really is). If I wanted selectable buttons, I would probably create `ToggleButton` and change the background based on their `IsChecked` property. The viewmodel wouldn't care about the background, it would interact with a `IsSelected` boolean or something like that.

Comment: My case is , I need select a group of buttons based on a condition, because in the future I add two buttons more "Left or Right" for example , I select **Left** and then the button with content 0,1 , in this example 0,1 & 0,0 need set the BackGround to yellow and the right one 0,2 no, Its posible set background to that buttons from ViewModel depends of a condition? Thanks

Comment: Well whatever... in order for the bindings to work individually, you will need individual properties for each button.

Comment: Oh god, in the real application I had +100 buttons, I can iterate the controls from view model and set individual background color or apply another style if they have the true conditions? Sorry for my noob questions

Comment: Well you can create a separate viewmodel for a button and then maintain a list of button viewmodels in your main viewmodel. Unfortunately I won't find the time to write an answer today, explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

roughly, and with little code being demonstrated (you can find more if you look for `ItemsControl`) you can do as **grek40** said.

your button will be an usercontrol (`ucMyButton`) with its own viewmodel and its properties.

in your mainview you will add an `ItemControl` and it will include a collection of buttons (`ObservableCollection<MyButtonViewModel> MyButtons { ..... }`)

then each MyButtonViewModel will be a separate button with its own Background property so each button can be set separately

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itmWrapPanel" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyButtons, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  

            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  
                    Background="White" 
                    AllowDrop="True" 
                    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=itmWrapPanel}" 
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=itmWrapPanel}"  />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate  >
            <local:ucMyButton  />

        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```