# Loop through dictionary key in XAML ? (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary

I want to dynamically create a view with a new datagrid foreach key in a dictionary. Is it possible to do this in XAML?

My dictionary is :
Dictionary < string, List< object > > 
The key is the title of the dictionary and the List of object will be display in the datagrid. 
I want to generate one datagrid foreach key in my dictionary.

For exemple if I have a those entries in my dictionary :

```
<"Toto", [{"prop1":"tata", "prop2":"titi"}, {"prop1":"tata2", "prop2":"titi2"}]>  
<"Tutu", [{"prop1":"tatax", "prop2":"titix"}]>
```

I want to display in my program this :

```
    TOTO                          TUTU
-------------                --------------
Prop1 | Prop2                Prop1  | Prop2  
------|------                -------|------
tata  | titi                 tatax  | titix  
tata2 | titi2
```

In ASP.NET you can do it with a @foreach in the middle of the view, but how can I generating it in XAML / WPF ?

Comment: use `ItemsControl` with appropriate ItemsPanel and ItemTemplate and bind ItemsSource to dictionary

Comment: Do you have some example ? I know how to directly bind the datagrid on my List of object, but I don't know how to deal with my dictionary (and I didn't find any exemple) ...

Comment: Dictionary implements IEnumerable of KeyValuePair. General approach for ItemsControl is applicable here. There are lots of examples for ItemsControl

Comment: an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47461158/5605739

Comment: Thank you, it is working well, it was exactly what I needed. @CelsoLívero your exemple help me so much. I will just ask to my question with the produced code to help other people if they have the same problem.

Comment: For the one who had downvote this post, can you explain in why my post is unclear or not usefull ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code working code I did with the help of @ASh and @CelsoLívero, I just post it to help other people if they have the same problem.

I have a `List<Tag>` in value of my dictionary, that's why I need to put `OneWay` (because it's a read only datagrid, and it fill to my needs) but if someone want to have a `TwoWay`binding, you will need to create an `ObservableCollection` instead of just a `List`.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemControlTags" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentModuleItem.DicoTags}"  
        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  
                Background="White"
                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=itemControlTags}" 
                Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=itemControlTags}"  />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"></TextBlock>
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                  CanUserAddRows="False" 
                  IsReadOnly="True" 
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                  Name="TagsDatagrid"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}">
                </DataGrid>
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Okay, now mark the answer as being correct, congratulations

Comment: I will, but it say "You can accept your own answer in 2 days" so, I will wait two more days